# What is the path to a local variable from hadoop fs, bash?

Tags: bash, hadoop

Windows user here. Will be a really simple answer, it must have been asked but I mustn't know the terminology to find the question here in Stack.

I'm trying to reference any file outside of the hadoop fs (hadoop filesystem?) on my Linux VM. An example is this:

```
hadoop fs -put home/udacity_training/data/access_logs.txt access_logs.txt
```

In the above call I'm trying to copy the file from the 'data' folder to my hadoop filesystem. However for every path I try reference I get 'no such file or directory' error. 
Even when trying to use 'copyFromLocal' like so:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal access_logs.txt access_logs.txt
```

It doesn't work!

Any help will be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following command

```
hadoop fs -put home/udacity_training/data/access_logs.txt access_logs.txt
```

You are telling `hadoop` to copy `access_logs.txt` from local file system to `access_logs.txt directory` in `hdfs`. What hadoop is doing is trying to find that directory inside home directory of the `hadoop user`

So you can create home directory of `hadoop user` with which you are running `hadoop commands` as

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir -f /user/Finn
```

I am assuming `Finn` is the `username`

Then you apply

```
hadoop fs -put home/udacity_training/data/access_logs.txt /user/Finn/
```

You will see that `access_logs.txt` should be copied

Comment: Thanks for this Ramesh

Comment: Great to hear that the answer helped. An upvote should help me too. :) Thanks

Comment: I can now I've got enough rep!